# What is the best way to have an embedded part of a page auto-refresh?

Tags: embed, meta-refresh

What would be the best way to do?

Direct code HTML/CSS/JavaScript options vs plugin options.

(But not the whole webpage is to refresh, only a specific part of the page.)

This is a ModX site. The webpage/website is fully customizable HTML code.

Comment: Do you control the embedded part of the page or is it 3rd party content?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller we have full root control of the page

Comment: You say "plugin", is this a WordPress site?  If not, tell us more

Comment: @Steve no, not WordPress. ModX

Comment: @Steve It fully customizable HTML code.

Comment: We use the modx CMS

Comment: I suggest you get onto the ModX forums.  ModX is pretty specific in how it works, users will know a lot more.  

FWIW I used ModX for a while and it is quite good, just that it can be overkill for a simple site.

Comment: @Steve this question is not how to use ModX. We're not having an issue with the content management system

Comment: In understand that.  But your page is within the context of ModX.  Something that works in a static HTML page or a dynamic PHP page or WordPress might not work in ModX.  If I was doing this I would look at AJAX/jQuery to update...but will that work in ModX?  WHo knows.

Comment: @Steve I'm not a modx rofessional, I've only worked with the content management system as it relates to the website. but the way I understand it, there are no limitations regarding what code you can use. I don't see why you should not be able to use any code libraries.

Comment: OK...Since you haven't had an answer here yet, I still think your best bet is ModX forum